# Could using 'self' inside a closure lead to a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-leaks

If I have a function within an object (a Backbone model in my case)...

```
doIt: function () {
    var self = this,  
        result = null;

    this.doMagic(function(){
        result = self.doWizardry();
    });    

    self = null;

    return result
}
```

...do I need to set self as null as I've done here, in order to avoid memory leaks?

Bonus question, will the closure's reference to 'result' cause a memory leak too?

Any advice on improving the efficiency of this type of structure would be much appreciated!

(Hopefully obvious that this is not a real function, just illustrative)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you even suspect that there would be a memory leak here?

Comment: I would take in account the following setence: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*. That is, first develop your application and free your mind of this kind of concerns during first stages of your developments. Memory leaks, CPU leeching or other performance *bugs* should be evaluated using profilers and when your application is being prepared for a production release.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - I agree with your phrase about premature optimization, but understanding what structures do and don't lead to memory leaks is not premature optimization - it's called writing good code the first time rather than trying to discover bugs and problems through testing later on.  While this particular question does not appear to illustrate a memory leak, one SHOULD know what structures do and you should avoid them when you first write your code.  That is not premature optimization.  That's writing good code.

Comment: @Fijjit - I think you'll have to illustrate some real code that actually does something to get better feedback on the code.  The code you've included doesn't cause a leak and doesn't even do anything other than add a method to the object so there isn't much more to comment on other than that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Then, OP should rephrase the question, because OP it's talking about "why this leads to a memory leak". Maybe it's more a codereview question: am I doing this fine so it won't produce memory leaks?"

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - as my answer illustrates, the OP is just operating under a wrong impression that this structure causes a memory leak.  But my point to you is that it's not premature optimization to understand what does and doesn't cause a memory leak.

Comment: @jfriend00 My point of view is concerning about this is premature optimization. You've too many things to think about instead of guessing a closure produces a memory leak :D

Comment: Thinking about and trying to avoid memory leaks is _definitely_ not premature optimization. Unfortunately that quote gets thrown around for the wrong reasons all the time. It simply means that you should not forfeit decoupled, clear and testable code for less decoupled, less clear or less testable, but optimized (for speed or memory) code, _until_ the need arises. Unfortunately it's being used as an excuse for writing crappy code from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  In fact, setting `self` to `null` before `this.doMamgic()` is called will also ruin the variable `self` such that `this.doMagic()` won't be able to use it because its value will have been cleared when `this.doMagic()` is actually trying to use it some time later.

Self references in Javascript do not by themselves lead to memory leaks.  The GC is smart enough to detect that.  If a whole object is unreachable by other JS, it doesn't matter how many references the object has to itself inside the object.

I see no particular reason in this code why using the variable `self` would lead to a memory leak and doing something like this is a well-established pattern for storing state that a callback can use (just like you're trying to do).

---

As for general advice, the point of the `doIt()` function looks like it has issues.  You appear to be trying to return the `result` value that was set by `this.doMagic()`, but `this.doMagic()` is not called while `doIt()` is executing, thus `result` will NEVER have a value when `doIt()` returns.

So, this whole structure appears flawed.  To know what to recommend would require understand what you're trying to accomplish and how you are calling/using this code which you have not disclosed.

Comment: Thanks, this answer and all the comments clarified it for me.  As for your second comment, the doMagic function would imaginarliy call the function it has been passed, which in turn will set result to the output of doWizardry, all of which would complete before doIt has returned.